# If Statement with Array Variables Out of Range Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement

I'm trying to search a user's contacts but one of my if statements is broken. It checks if the character at a certain index of the input matches the character of the same index of the givenName, familyName, and phoneNumber. My problem is that sometimes the number of characters entered is more than the number of characters in the givenName, familyName, or phoneNumber. This makes my if statement compare the character at a certain index of the input and the character at an index that doesn't exist. For instance, it compares charInput[2] to charGivenName[2] but charGivenName only has values at charGivenName[0] and charGivenName[1]. Since charGivenName[2] doesn't exist, my apps crashes.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
@IBAction func contactTextFieldChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    if contactTextField.text != "" {

        contactTableView.isHidden = false

        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
        do {

            try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request){
                (contact, stop) in

                self.contacts.append(contact)

                for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {

                    if phoneNumber.value.stringValue != ""{

                        let charGivenName = Array(contact.givenName)
                        let charFamilyName = Array(contact.familyName)
                        let charNumber = Array(phoneNumber.value.stringValue)
                        let charInput = Array(self.contactTextField.text!)
                        var matchBool = false

                        for inputCount in (0...charInput.count - 1) {

                            if charNumber[inputCount] == charInput[inputCount] || charGivenName[inputCount] == charInput[inputCount] || charFamilyName[inputCount] == charInput[inputCount]{

                                matchBool = true

                            } else {

                                matchBool = false
                                break

                            }

                            if matchBool == true {

                                print("\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName) \(phoneNumber.value.stringValue)")

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {

            print("Error fetching contacts")

        }
    }
    if contactTextField.text == ""{

        contactTableView.isHidden = true

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the end goal? why compare to one character?

Comment: Users search for contacts to add to a chat. Results should start appearing as they start typing. They shouldn't have to write the entire name 'John' for John's contact info to appear, they should be able to write 'Jo' and a list of contacts whose names match 'Jo' (such as Joe, Johnny, Jon, Jonathan) should appear.

Comment: Why not implement a search bar? [Here is a video to show you how](https://youtu.be/zgP_VHhkroE)

Comment: I guess that could work. I'll try it out. If I can't find a way to fix my code I'll probably just use that. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If it already exists, there is no need to do all that work again!

Comment: Seconding @Jake, don't reinvent the wheel. But because you'll see `Array` a lot during your career--unrelated to search bars--here's a thought. If one array is too short, then there's really nothing you can do except stop comparing before you go off the end.